# How to add font awesome to laravel 5.6 project?

Tags: css, laravel, font-awesome, laravel-blade

I want to add font awesome to my laravel project. I downloaded font awesome and add it to css directory in public and fonts to fonts directory and I addressed it as fllowing:

```
rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/font-awesome.min.css') }}"
```

But when I use something like `class="fas fa-download"` it is not showing any thing.

What is wrong?

Comment: `fas fa-download` or `fa fa-download` ?

Comment: according to their wesite fas fa-download.

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: the version is 5.2.0

Comment: View page source and confirm that your font awesome files are properly linked.

Comment: there was no problem inly i was linking to .css from wrong file :).

Comment: Cool... Cheers... Happy coding.

Comment: Which font awesome version did you download? Was it a direct download or did you use something like npm? In the console or the network tab of your browser are you getting any errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I will suggest, 
Say you working with view example: welcome.blade.php,
if you downloaded the font awesome(put the downloaded file **in this case the fontawesome-all.min.css,  in public>css folder of your laravel project). 
In my case I'm using this version Font Awesome Free 5.0.13.

then add this link

```
<!-- Font Awesome Icons  -->
<link href="{{ asset('css/fontawesome-all.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

hope it helps.